# Constructing the finite-dimensional representations of $\frak{sl}_3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The finite-dimensional representations of $\frak{sl}_2$ can be constructed explicitly as partial differentiation of polynomials in two variables. Does a similar explicit construction exist for the finite-dimensional representations of $\frak{sl}_3$?

Comment: Yes, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426423/a-representation-of-fraksl-n-as-partial-derivatives-on-polynomials).

Comment: To be clear, we can construct equivalent representations of this form, but they don't cover all possible representations. For that you can take tensor products (some people might still refer to these as polynomials sometimes but they are not symmetric in general)

Comment: @Callum: So for $\frak{sl}_3$ we have two fundamental weights $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. Which of the irreps $a\pi_1 + b\pi_2$ can be realised in this way?

Comment: @ZoltanFleishman the rep of highest weight $a\pi_1$ can be realised as the (symmetric) homogeneous polynomials of degree $a$ in $V$. You can also realise the reps of highest weight $b\pi_2$ similarly as polynomials but for $V^*$.

Comment: @Callum So are there explicit constructions for the irrupts $a\pi_1+b\pi_2$ when $a$ and $b$ are both non-zero?

Comment: Yes, you can construct it as a subset of $S^{a}(V) \otimes S^{b}(V^*)$. Specifically as the kernel of the contraction map $i_{a,b}: S^{a}(V) \otimes S^{b}(V^*) \to S^{a-1}(V) \otimes S^{b-1}(V^*)$. See Fulton and Harris's *Representation Theory* Section 13.2 for more details.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks a lot.